# Trying to insert information into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to insert this information but im getting this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /storage/ssd2/324/18431324/public_html/processoadicionarcarros.php:248 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd2/324/18431324/public_html/processoadicionarcarros.php on line 248`

Here is my code for inserting:

```
    $iduser = $_SESSION['iduser'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO carros (marca, modelo, submodelo, combustivel, mesReg, anoReg, quilometros, cilindrada, potencia, aceitaRetoma, cor, tipoCor, tipoCaixa, nPortas, lotacao, nMudancas, registo, origem, livroRevisoesCompleto, naoFumador, segundaChave, anunciante, imagemPrincipal, imagemPrincipalLoc, imagemUm, imagemUmLoc, imagemDois, imagemDoisLoc, imagemTres, imagemTresLoc, imagemQuatro, imagemQuatroLoc, imagemCinco, imagemCincoLoc, imagemSeis, imagemSeisLoc, imagemSete, imagemSeteLoc, userid) VALUES (UPPER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))";
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($query);
   **line 248 -** $stmt -> bind_param("sssssiiiissssiiiisssssssssssssssssssssi", $marca, $modelo, $submodelo, $combustivel, $mesReg, $anoReg, $quilometros, $cilindrada, $potencia, $acRetoma, $cor, $tipoPintura, $tipoCaixa, $nPortas, $lotacao, $nMudancas, $registo, $origem, $livroRevisoes, $fumador, $segChave, $anunciante, $imgPrincipalNewName, $imgPrincipalDestino, $imagemUmNewName, $imagemUmDestino, $imagemDoisNewName, $imagemDoisDestino, $imagemTresNewName, $imagemTresDestino, $imagemQuatroNewName, $imagemQuatroDestino, $imagemCincoNewName, $imagemCincoDestino, $imagemSeisNewName, $imagemSeisDestino, $imagemSeteNewName, $imagemSeteDestino, $iduser);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
```

Database photo:

[image]

If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Edit: If I remove UPPER it works, I just dont understand what is wrong with UPPER, can someone explain please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with mysqli problems? mysqli\_fetch\_array(): Argument #1 must be of type mysqli\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-deal-with-mysqli-problems-mysqli-fetch-array-argument-1-must-be-of-t)

Comment: If you bothered to check for errors you'd know that your `prepare` has failed, and why. Take a look at the correct syntax for `UPPER()`

Comment: I dont understand, what is wrong with `UPPER()` can you tell me if you dont mind please ?

Comment: Hi @MiguelF, it can only accept one parameter, looks like you're passing multiple.

Comment: Thank you guys, I already figured it out.

Comment: No worries, click the tick next to your answer to accept it. :)

Comment: I cant, I need to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO carros (marca, modelo, submodelo, combustivel, mesReg, anoReg, quilometros, cilindrada, potencia, aceitaRetoma, cor, tipoCor, tipoCaixa, nPortas, lotacao, nMudancas, registo, origem, livroRevisoesCompleto, naoFumador, segundaChave, anunciante, imagemPrincipal, imagemPrincipalLoc, imagemUm, imagemUmLoc, imagemDois, imagemDoisLoc, imagemTres, imagemTresLoc, imagemQuatro, imagemQuatroLoc, imagemCinco, imagemCincoLoc, imagemSeis, imagemSeisLoc, imagemSete, imagemSeteLoc, userid) VALUES (UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?),UPPER(?))";
```

instead of:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO carros (marca, modelo, submodelo, combustivel, mesReg, anoReg, quilometros, cilindrada, potencia, aceitaRetoma, cor, tipoCor, tipoCaixa, nPortas, lotacao, nMudancas, registo, origem, livroRevisoesCompleto, naoFumador, segundaChave, anunciante, imagemPrincipal, imagemPrincipalLoc, imagemUm, imagemUmLoc, imagemDois, imagemDoisLoc, imagemTres, imagemTresLoc, imagemQuatro, imagemQuatroLoc, imagemCinco, imagemCincoLoc, imagemSeis, imagemSeisLoc, imagemSete, imagemSeteLoc, userid) VALUES (UPPER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))";
```

Because UPPER() can only accept one parameter.